# Perl subroutine assistance

Tags: perl, multidimensional-array, subroutine

Using [`Data::Dumper`](https://metacpan.org/module/Data%3a%3aDumper) and [`List::Util`](https://metacpan.org/module/List%3a%3aUtil) I'm able to sum the total of each row within my array with a subroutine. This part is correct.

With an easier approach I attempted to print the grand total of all numbers with a separate subroutine called `get_grandtotal`. This returns incorrect numbers.

My question is how do I print the correct grand total?

And what modifications would I use to print the column total (instead of the row total) using a similar structure in `get_row(@values)`.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl  
use 5.10.1; 
use warnings; 
use strict; 

use List::Util qw(sum); 
use Data::Dumper;

my @values = ( 
    [ 6, 5, 13 ], 
    [ 35, 9, 6 ], 
    [ 65, 255, 54 ] 
); 

get_row(@values);

sub get_row { 
    my @total;
    foreach my $row (@_) { 
        say join ' ', @$row; 
        push @total, sum @$row;
    }     
    say Data::Dumper->Dump( [ \@total ], [ qw(*Row_Total) ] );
}

my $sum = 0;
sub get_grandtotal() {    
    foreach (@values) {
        $sum += $_;
    }
    print "Grand Total = $sum\n"; 
}

get_grandtotal();
```

**Output**

```
6 5 13
35 9 6
65 255 54
@Row_Total = (
               '24',
               '50',
               '374'
             );

Grand Total = 61899232
```

Comment: some style notes: you are declaring get_grandtotal with a prototype; this has little use and can be confusing, so don't.  do pass @values to get_grandtotal and loop over @_, though.

Comment: trivially, `$sum = sum map @$_, @values`

Answer (score 2):

You are trying to add together array references in

```
$sum += $_;
```

change this to

```
$sum += sum @$_;
```

and your code will work.

This subroutine uses `map` to extract the columns from the array, and prints the totals

```
sub get_column {

    my @total;
    foreach my $i (0 .. $#{$values[0]}) {
        my @column = map $_->[$i], @values;
        say join ' ', @column; 
        push @total, sum @column;
    }     

    say Data::Dumper->Dump( [ \@total], [ qw(*Column_Total) ] );
}
```

**output**

```
6 35 65
5 9 255
13 6 54
@Column_Total = (
                  '106',
                  '269',
                  '73'
                );
```